# hide column based on cell font color in a row vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide columns based on cell font color in first row. Here I want to hide columns if cells in first row has black as font color. Now, I dont want to define a range since my data varies each week so I can have 10 columns this week and 20 next week, and I would like to keep my codes dynamic.

It looks like my vba codes went through (by pressing **F8**) without any issues but nothing happens. I also posted a sample below along with the desire result.

```
 Sub test()
 Dim i As Range

  For Each i In Rows(1)
       If i.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
         i.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
            i.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        End If
Next i

 End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what's odd is if I am at result tab and run my vba codes it will actually un-hide column A & C, not sure if the logic of my codes is wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the cells in the range. And you don't need the If statement. Try:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = c.Font.Color = 0
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with the Cells in the first row:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideBlackHeaders()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, headerRow As Range, cel As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1    'Use the CodeName of the sheet

    Set headerRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1)

    For Each cel In headerRow.Cells

        cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = (cel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0))

    Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A little too late but try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Last column
    lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To lColumn
        If Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```